# Laravel Schedule running before the specified conditions

Tags: laravel

I have the following code in Kernel.php. The purpose is to run the command between 23:000 and 04:00

```
$schedule->command('moving:vehicles -vvv')
            ->between('23:00', '04:00')
            ->everyTenMinutes();
```

However, the cron starts executing the command at 17H00. I have tried to replicate the same by send emails into mailtrap and I get different results.

Comment: Might be something related to the timezone or the time on the server itself. Have a look at how Laravel Scheduler allows you to control the timezone here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#timezones

Comment: It's not the timezone, config/app.php I have already configured the timezone. 'timezone' => 'Africa/Johannesburg',

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/28943
The link above explains why the schedule was not running as intended. It was a bug in Laravel 5.x and it was resolved in version 6. I changed direction to use https://crontab.guru/#*/10_0-4,23_*_* to solve the issue I faced.